# vb.net - Populating a combobox with multiple properties from object

Tags: vb.net, collections

Using vb.net (vs2005), how do I populate a combo box with multiple property values from an object? Right now I'm iterating a collection of objects and adding the name property of each object to the combo box. I'd like to add multiple properties from the object to the list. For now, I'd be happy if they appeared comma separated in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private _items As New List(Of Person)  'you will need to fill this with data!'

Private Sub Populate()

  For i As Integer = 0 To _items.count - 1
    lst.items.add(_items(i).Name & ", " & _items(i).Age)
  Next

End Sub
```

This will populate your listbox (which i have called lst) something like this:

```
Dave, 18
John, 21
Morgan, 23
Jen, 19
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a winforms environment, override the ToStirng() method, and simply add the whole object to the items collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the method by yourself. 
Or you are lazy like me. 
Try this multi column combo box
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultcs.aspx